# implement inheritance in tables or not

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a question and now I'm learning little by little on my own what is database.

good results that I have a computer retail store and the store is in Personal Service (Manager, Administrator, vendor and Support) and Clients (natural and legal), all these must have a user name and password you will have privileges access (User, Service Personnel).

As the design would make it?. what I want is to manage access privileges and so avoid some table inheritance, but not if it should apply in my case or only with Access, because from a table called PERSON alleged and another table called SALES, if for example, a person is a seller and one other staff person is a user who will buy anything at the table SALE I want to save the data of seller personnel and ladders, and if you only have one table called pERSON Would that double relationship?, should be two of the FK ID PERSON?

Comment: well if you don't like redundant data storage you might only store the essential data per table and combine them with joins. to ease that you may use views that can clean up alot if e.g. natural joins are used to combine the tables. just my 2 cents on that :)

Answer (score 0):

In a good model, you have to think in infinite-1, infinite-infinite, 1-1 relations.
So, a good model must be:

- every table for a kind of object (persons, sales, etc)
- every group of kind (administrator, sellerman, buyer, etc)
- if you have infinite tables, you must create a table for relations.

e.g. for infinite-infinite (1 person can has 1 or more kind):

```
PERSONS
- Person_ID
- Firstname
- Lastname
- Address

WORK
-Work_ID
-Kind (Administrator, seller, etc)

REL_PERS_WORK
-Rel_Id
-Person_ID (from PERSONS table)
-Work_ID (from WORK table)
```

Comment: And if you say, that if I want a person to have a username and password to access the system, that it would put on that table, a table PERSON or if you would have to create another table linked one to one with the table PERSON

Comment: It's depends if you think a person can access with one or more username. It's a good idea normalize the tables, but denormalize it's great too. Query one table is more quick and effective than two tables. For 1-1 and is not another entity, use the same table. Take in mind also if in a near future you will divide this information, for example, a table with username, password, points, nickname, etc etc etc. The main idea is try to not repeat information.

Comment: There's no a "good" way or a "bad" way. It's depends for the flexibility of your objects and effective procedures. In another case, i ever store the passwords in a MD5 encryption format (or any ONE-WAY method) in a separate table that I never query directly from the software, everytime from a stored procedure. And I never query for the password, ever for the id.